# How to transform factor into integer in S4 `DataFrame`?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-s4

I obtained tabular data as output after several workflows, this output was stored in `S4Vectors::DataFrame` class. I intend to transform factored column into the integer. Yes, I tried to use `as.integer` to drop the factor, but I got a matrix. I want to keep them in `DataFrame` object. Can anyone point me how to preserve original class type after transforming factor into the integer?

I got this tabular data in `DataFrame`:
(before run `DF`, installing `S4Vectors` is needed : `library(S4Vectors)` )

```
DF <- DataFrame(
    query=factor(c(7,17,15,4,7,15,13,19,4,6,13,19,6,11,17,10,11,10)),
    subject=factor(c(7,17,15,4,21,21,13,13,20,20,19,19,6,11,9,1,18,10)),
    score=c(4,4,7,8,11,11,12,12,13,13,13,13,15,21,38,48,49,54)
)
```

I tried in this way:

```
res <- sapply(DF, function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x))
        as.integer(x)
    x
})
```

my solution is not desired for me because `res` becomes matrix and code is a bit of inefficient. I want to have simplest, shortest answer on this (only one line code to make this happen). After transforming the factor column into the integer, I want to keep it as `DataFrame`.

Note that I have special reason to keep it `DataFrame`. I intend to make the solution as simple as possible (both computationally cheaper and efficient).

This is my desired output:

```
desiredDF <- DataFrame(
    query=as.integer(c(7,17,15,4,7,15,13,19,4,6,13,19,6,11,17,10,11,10)),
    subject=as.integer(c(7,17,15,4,21,21,13,13,20,20,19,19,6,11,9,1,18,10)),
    score=c(4,4,7,8,11,11,12,12,13,13,13,13,15,21,38,48,49,54)
)
```

How can I transform the factored column in `DF` into integer while keep them in `DataFrame` class ? Any idea to make this happen? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You were very close

```
res <- data.frame(sapply(DF, function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x))
      as.integer(x)
    x
}))
```

Comment: I need even more simplest approach to get this done. Is that possible to do this only one line code? Is there any function to simplify above code?

Comment: Dunno man, `sapply` is actually pretty efficient. This function also gives you flexibility so it can be used with any `data.frame` of any `colnames`